# HashSet - Is accessing/finding a object in HashSet O(1)?

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

Average complexity of accessing a particular object/data in an array is O(n) , here n is array length.
Is it O(1) for finding an element in HashSet for Java?

```
HashSet<String> set=new HashSet<String>();  
......
System.out.print(set.contains(Some_string);
```

Is `contains(String)` method performing at O(1)?

Comment: Yes in short because it uses hashing technique.

Comment: an idealized hashset is O(1)

Comment: [java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/](https://simplenotions.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/)

Comment: idealized Hashset ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The basic operations (add, remove, contains, and size) run in constant time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: You omitted the suffix "assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets". Actually this assumption is wrong in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, accessing and finding an element in HashSet is O(1).

HashSet stores elements using the hashing technique. Another important property of HashSet is that it contains only unique elements. For example you can check if the element already exists in HashSet.

```
HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<String();
if(hs.add(10) == false) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: There is a `contains()` method. So we do not need to do `hs.add(10) == false`. Instead we could do `hs.contains(10)`.